# could not highlight gmail content up to 6

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension which is about fetching the list of topics from the server and find if those topics match with the currently opened gmail messages or not, if found then highlight that topic otherwise don't. But if already 6 topics are matched then it should not check or highlight other topics.

I have used the treewalker for crawling the gmail contents so the matched content will get highlighted as follow

```
function searchPage(topics) {
    highlightAllWords(topics);
}

var highlightAllWords = function(topics) {
    Object.keys(topics.topics).forEach(function(topic) {
        highlightTopic(topic);
    })
}

function highlightTopic(topic) {
    let found = 0;
    if (topic == null || topic.length === 0) return;
    var topicRegex = new RegExp(topic, 'gi');
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        {
            acceptNode: function(node) {
                var result = NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
                if (topicRegex.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                    found += 1
                    console.log('found', found);
                    if (found <= 6) {
                        console.log('foound less than 6', found)
                        result = NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
                        return result;
                    }
                };
            }
        }, false
    )

    var skipTagName = {
        "NOSCRIPT": true,
        "SCRIPT": true,
        "STYLE": true
    }

    var nodeList = [];
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        if (!skipTagName[treeWalker.currentNode.parentNode.tagName]) {
            nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
        }
    }

    nodeList.forEach(function (n) {
        var rangeList = [];
        // find sub-string ranges
        var startingIndex = 0;
        do {
            // console.log(word, startingIndex, n.parentNode, n.textContent);
            startingIndex = n.textContent.indexOf(topic, startingIndex + 1);
            if (startingIndex !== -1) {
                var topicRange = document.createRange();
                topicRange.setStart(n, startingIndex);
                topicRange.setEnd(n, startingIndex + topic.length);
                rangeList.push(topicRange);
            }
        } while (startingIndex !== -1);

        // highlight all ranges
        rangeList.forEach(function (r) {
            highlightRange(r);
        });
    }); 
}


// highlight the keyword by surround it by `i`
var highlightRange = function (range) {
    const bgColorCode = '#000000';
    var anchor = document.createElement("A");
    var selectorName = anchor.className = "highlighted_text";
    anchor.classList.add("highlighted_text");

    // range.surroundContents(iNode) will throw exception if word across multi tag
    if (!ruleExistenceDict[bgColorCode]) {
        sheet.insertRule([".", selectorName, " { background: #", bgColorCode, " !important; }"].join(""), 0);
        ruleExistenceDict[bgColorCode] = true;
        console.log(sheet);
    }
    anchor.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    anchor.href = `https://google.com/?search=${
                        range.extractContents()
                    }`;
    range.insertNode(anchor);
};
```

It highlights the matched content in gmail messages but does highlights more than 6 contents. I have taken the screenshot and it is something like this

[image]

update after counter increased and checked in treewalker.nextnode()

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntax errors in your code. You are missing semicolon at end of this statement

```
found += 1;
```

Secondly, there is also one extra ";" at the end of function(node).

And You can add the counter check in the following code snippet as

```
var count=1;
while (treeWalker.nextNode() && count<=6) {
    if (!skipTagName[treeWalker.currentNode.parentNode.tagName]) {
        nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
        count=count+1;
    }
}
```

So, the final script for the function highlightTopic(topic) will look like

```
function highlightTopic(topic) {
let found = 0;
if (topic == null || topic.length === 0) return;
var topicRegex = new RegExp(topic, 'gi');
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    {
        acceptNode: function(node) {
            var result = NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
            if (topicRegex.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                found += 1;
                console.log('found', found);
                if (found <= 6) {
                    console.log('foound less than 6', found)
                    result = NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }, false
)

var skipTagName = {
    "NOSCRIPT": true,
    "SCRIPT": true,
    "STYLE": true
}

var nodeList = [];
var count=1;
while (treeWalker.nextNode() && count<=6) {
    if (!skipTagName[treeWalker.currentNode.parentNode.tagName]) {
        nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
        count=count+1;
        console.log('count:'+count);
    }
}

nodeList.forEach(function (n) {
    var rangeList = [];
    // find sub-string ranges
    var startingIndex = 0;
    do {
        // console.log(word, startingIndex, n.parentNode, n.textContent);
        startingIndex = n.textContent.indexOf(topic, startingIndex + 1);
        if (startingIndex !== -1) {
            var topicRange = document.createRange();
            topicRange.setStart(n, startingIndex);
            topicRange.setEnd(n, startingIndex + topic.length);
            rangeList.push(topicRange);
        }
    } while (startingIndex !== -1);

    // highlight all ranges
    rangeList.forEach(function (r) {
        highlightRange(r);
    });
});
```

}

Please update me if it worked.

Thanks

**Edit:**

And also update the function highlightAllWords as follow:

```
var highlightAllWords = function(topics) {

var count=1;
Object.keys(topics.topics).forEach(function(topic) {
    if(count<=6){

    highlightTopic(topic);
    console.log('counter:'+count);
    if (topic != null && topic.length != 0)
        count=count+1;

    }

})
```

}

Comment: I consoled the count just beneath count assignment and it shows only 1 not 2, 3 but only 1

Comment: And what was the console output after running my code?

Comment: Updated the code in my answer. Please also update the highlightAllWords function as I did in my answer. And then let me know if it worked. And also post the screenshot if still it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: only 4 are highlighted instead of 6 now.

Comment: I've updated the code of highlightAllWords again. Please try the updated code and let me know. It will surely work now

Comment: Have you tested?

Comment: I removed the counter related part from all the blocks except highlightAllWords function and it worked but there is one problem. Once it highlights 6 words if i go back and again open that message or any other message, that highlightAllWords function does not run because no logs is printed in console and highlight is also not shown

Comment: Please mark the answer if it worked. And start start new thread for the new issue.

Comment: marked it as solved as it was about highlighting max 6 words only. Here is a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413146/highlighting-works-at-initial-but-does-not-when-hash-changes