# Highlighting works initially but does not when hash changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension, which is about fetching the list of topics from the server and find if those topics match with the currently opened Gmail messages or not, if found then highlight that topic otherwise don't.

But if already 6 topics are matched, then it should not check or highlight other topics. This one is working but now I have a problem like if I go back from the current message and again come to that message then highlight won't be shown. Also if I open another message, the highlight is not done.

If I remove the code of counter check from the following snippet it works but this will highlight all the topics that are matched instead of just max 6 topics.

```
var count = 1;
var highlightAllWords = function(topics) {
  Object.keys(topics.topics).forEach(function(topic) {
    if (count <= 6) {
      highlightTopic(topic);
      if (topic !== null || !topic.length) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  });
};

// init highlight CSS
var ruleExistenceDict = {};
var sheet = (function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('')); // WebKit hack @@
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return style.sheet;
})();

var topicData = {
  topics: {
    hostname: 4,
    cto: 19,
    aws: 382,
    its: 26,
    repo: 15,
    unsubscribe: 65,
    bitbucket: 313,
    having: 28,
    devops: 414,
    frontend: 25,
    stepin: 105,
    username: 121,
    deployed: 24,
    vimeo: 460,
    gmail: 156,
    rds: 486,
    clicked: 9,
    lai: 850
  }
};

function fetchTopics() {
  // api call will be done here but for now its done with dummy object
  searchPage(topicData);
}

function searchPage(topics) {
  highlightAllWords(topics);
}

var count = 1;
var highlightAllWords = function(topics) {
  Object.keys(topics.topics).forEach(function(topic) {
    if (count <= 6) {
      highlightTopic(topic);
      if (topic !== null || !topic.length) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  });
};

function highlightTopic(topic) {
  // let found = 0;
  let isCompleted = false;
  if (topic == null || topic.length === 0) return;
  var topicRegex = new RegExp(topic, 'gi');
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
      acceptNode: function(node) {
        var result = NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        if (topicRegex.test(node.nodeValue)) {
          // found += 1;
          // if (found <= 6) {
          result = NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
          return result;
          // }
        }
      }
    },
    false
  );

  var skipTagName = {
    NOSCRIPT: true,
    SCRIPT: true,
    STYLE: true
  };

  var nodeList = [];
  // let count = 1;
  console.log('count near nextNode', count);
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    if (!skipTagName[treeWalker.currentNode.parentNode.tagName]) {
      nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
      // count = count + 1;
      // console.log('count:' + count);
    }
  }

  nodeList.forEach(function(n) {
    var rangeList = [];
    // find sub-string ranges
    var startingIndex = 0;
    do {
      // console.log(word, startingIndex, n.parentNode, n.textContent);
      startingIndex = n.textContent.indexOf(topic, startingIndex + 1);
      if (startingIndex !== -1) {
        var topicRange = document.createRange();
        topicRange.setStart(n, startingIndex);
        topicRange.setEnd(n, startingIndex + topic.length);
        rangeList.push(topicRange);
      }
    } while (startingIndex !== -1);

    // highlight all ranges
    rangeList.forEach(function(r) {
      highlightRange(r);
    });
  });
}

var highlightRange = function(range) {
  const bgColorCode = '#000000';
  var anchor = document.createElement('A');
  var selectorName = (anchor.className = 'highlighted_text');
  anchor.classList.add('highlighted_text');
  if (!ruleExistenceDict[bgColorCode]) {
    sheet.insertRule(
      [
        '.',
        selectorName,
        ' { background: #',
        bgColorCode,
        ' !important; }'
      ].join(''),
      0
    );
    ruleExistenceDict[bgColorCode] = true;
    console.log(sheet);
  }
  anchor.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  anchor.href = `https://app.com/profile/topics/${range.extractContents()}`;
  range.insertNode(anchor);
};
```

Here is the full code:

https://gist.github.com/MilanRgm/5d6b9861be1326ba8b049ccfb6c3b376

Comment: please condense your code into something smaller.

Comment: Thanks and edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the count variable inside the function, so that every time you refresh the page, the count will start from 1 again. Please update your code as follows:

```
var highlightAllWords = function(topics) {

  var count = 1;

  Object.keys(topics.topics).forEach(function(topic) {

    if (count <= 6) {
        highlightTopic(topic);

        if (topic !== null || !topic.length) {
           count += 1;
        }
    }
});
};
```

Comment: so it work in totality. I mean not 6 topics per message but 6 topics in all gmail messages

Comment: nup. I wanted max 6 topic to be shown in each message but it is highlighting 6 messages in total so if in one message it highlights 6 messages then in other messages it wont highlight

Comment: Yeah I understand that. 
That's why I have updated the code and initialised the count variable inside the function instead of the global one. Please have a look on updated code and apply it and then let me know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure to refresh your chrome extension after updating the code. It should surely work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176333/discussion-between-serenity-and-abdul-jabbar).